# how to make a keycode work for cyrillic

Tags: javascript

Below code work only for latin **n**, but how to make it work for cyrillic **н**

```
if(event.keyCode === 78) {
console.log('okay');
}
```

And is weird that this code works if i change the keyboard layout different from US and click on latin N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but I'm going to assume you want to get the character associated with typing in a cyrillic character on a keyboard. If so, I imagine you're using the wrong event (`keydown` or `keyup`) when the correct event is `keypress`. `keydown` and `keyup` tell you about the physical key pressed while `keypress` tells you about the character that was typed. Here's a simple cross-browser example of how to get the typed character:

```
document.onkeypress = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var charCode = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    var typedChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert("Typed character: " + typedChar);
};
```

Here's the definitive reference for JavaScript keyboard events: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 0):

Cyrillic **н** is not a part of first 127 characters of UTF8 therefore your code does not work. You could try using appropriate code for **н**, that is 1085, if it makes any sense:

```
if(event.keyCode === 1085) {
    console.log('okay');
}
```

As a side note, there is no one-to-one relationship between cyrillic and latin characters - I would suggest thinking twice before trying to invent one.