# Angularjs keyup vs keypress with cyrillic letters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have directive with following code:

```
return {
   restrict: 'A',
   scope: {
      fn: '&callback',
      value:'=value'
   },
   link: function ( scope, element, attr ) {
      element.on( 'keyup', function ( event ) {
         if ( event.keyCode >= 1072 && event.keyCode <= 1103 ) {
             var t = scope;
             scope.fn();
         } else {
             event.preventDefault();
         }
    } )
}
```

}

KeyUp event does not return keycode for cyrillic letters, but keypress event does. How can I get current language or keycode in keyUp event?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376706/how-to-make-a-keycode-work-for-cyrillic - answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup)** and **[KeyDown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown)** are supposed to return a key code, and can't does what you need, but **Keypress** event returns a character code, so I think you have to depend on it.

I hope that's help, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is going good way.
**keyUp/keyDown** event object having **keyCode/which**

I got this problem once in the Mozilla Firefox, why because keyCode is not working in the Mozilla